# Calculate mean after new recording

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, mean

I´m reading some excel files where I want to calculate the mean of the column 'Duration' but I want to see the change in mean after recording 1, 2, 3 and so on. So for the below table it would be:

`Mean1 = (3+3+3/3)`

`Mean2 = (3+3+3+4+6/5)`

`Mean3 = (3+3+3+4+6+4+3+1+4/9)`

Each file can have different number of recordings (but always starting from 1) and different number of durations for each recording.

Is is possible in Python to make a script that does this automatically?

| Recording | Duration |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you could do [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) "Recording" and get the ratio of the cumulated [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) and cumulated [`count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) (using [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html)):

```
g = df.groupby('Recording')['Duration']
s = g.sum().cumsum()/g.count().cumsum()
```

output:

```
Recording
1    3.000000
2    3.800000
3    3.444444
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

intermediates:

```
>>> g.sum().cumsum()
Recording
1     9
2    19
3    31
Name: Duration, dtype: int64

>>> g.count().cumsum()
Recording
1    3
2    5
3    9
Name: Duration, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

You can count average by defintion - first get `sum` and count per `Recording`, add cumulative sum by [`DataFrame.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) and for mean divide `sum` by `size` columns:

```
df = df.groupby('Recording')['Duration'].agg(['sum','size']).cumsum().reset_index()
df['avg'] = df.pop('sum').div(df.pop('size'))
print (df)
   Recording       avg
0          1  3.000000
1          2  3.800000
2          3  3.444444
```